# ItemsControl ItemTemplate Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, .net-4.0, itemscontrol, itemtemplate

In WPF4.0, I have a class that contains other class types as properties (combining multiple data types for display).  Something like:

```
public partial class Owner
{
     public string OwnerName { get; set; }
     public int    OwnerId   { get; set; }
}

partial class ForDisplay
{
    public Owner OwnerData { get; set; }
    public int Credit { get; set; }
}
```

In my window, I have an ItemsControl with the following (clipped for clarity):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <local:MyDisplayControl 
                OwnerName={Binding OwnerData.OwnerName}
                Credit={Binding Credit} />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I then get a collection of display information from the data layer, and set the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl` to this collection.  The "Credit" property gets displayed correctly, but the OwnerName property does not.  Instead, I get a binding error:

> Error 40: BindingExpression path
> error: 'OwnerName' property not found
> on 'object' ''ForDisplay'
> (HashCode=449124874)'.
> BindingExpression:Path=OwnerName;
> DataItem='ForDisplay'
> (HashCode=449124874); target element
> is 'TextBlock' (Name=txtOwnerName');
> target property is 'Text' (type
> 'String')

I don't understand why this is attempting to look for the OwnerName property in the ForDisplay class, rather than in the Owner class from the ForDisplay OwnerData property.

**Edit**
It appears that it has something to do with using the custom control.  If I bind the same properties to a `TextBlock`, they work correctly.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
              <local:MyDisplayControl 
                        OwnerName={Binding OwnerData.OwnerName}
                        Credit={Binding Credit} />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding OwnerData.OwnerName}" />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Credit}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Somehow, it's trying to find the OwnerName property on ForDisplay object. Use the following link to debug : http://wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html. One more question, Is OwnerName property on your MyDisplayControl a dependency property?

Comment: I see nothing wrong, assuming what you clipped isn't hiding anything relevant.  Have you tried clean/rebuild of the solution?  I hate this suggestion as it's equivalent to telling you to "reboot", but I have a databinding situation that SHOULD work but doesn't, I find that a clean/rebuild sometimes fixes it.  Not sure why.

Comment: A tentative guess: change the Binding to explicitly set the Path. ie "OwnerName={Binding Path=OwnerData.OwnerName}"

Comment: My design is in same way . but it is throwing NullReferenceException at `<DataTemplate>`

Answer (score 12):

Are you sure the code you posted here IS the code you use in your solution? Because, this code works for me :

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OwnerData.OwnerName}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Credit}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Window's Loaded Event

```
ObservableCollection<ForDisplay> items = new ObservableCollection<ForDisplay>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    items.Add(new ForDisplay() { OwnerData = new Owner() { OwnerId = i + 1, OwnerName = String.Format("Owner #{0}", i + 1) }, Credit = i + 1 });
}

DataContext = items;
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the custom control.  See edit of question.