# Binding an UserControl with a constructor to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, caliburn

Just started using Caliburn and WPF and got stuck on including an UserControl with a parameter to my Window.

Got one class named `Item` with a property named `SellPrice` which returns a `Money` object. I want to transfer this `Money` object to a UserControl to format the data in this object. How do I transfer the object? Do I need the use the constructor?

MainView.xaml

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sell Price">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <local:MoneyControlView/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Above code works fine if there wouldn't be any parameter but how do I pass the `Money` object?

I did try to do it via DependencyProperty as follows:

```
public partial class MoneyControlView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MoneyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
    (
            "Money",
            typeof(Money),
            typeof(MoneyControlView),
            new PropertyMetadata(new Money())
    );

    public Money Money
    {
        get { return (Money)GetValue(MoneyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MoneyProperty, value); }
    }

    public MoneyControlView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MoneyControlViewModel(Money);
    }
}
```

However, when using it:

```
<local:MoneyControlView Money="{Binding BuyPrice}"/>
```

it doesn't work. the Property remains empty.

Comment: One issue - change Collection<Item> to ObservableCollection<Item> from System.ComponentModel.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Load the View of the ViewModel in your MainView?

Comment: @Ryan Is there any specific reason for changing this? Never had any problems with my custom class.

Comment: @lll Indeed, passing data to the View and display it in my MainView after formatting

Comment: @Mostey ObservableCollection is a notification friendly collection, so  WPF and Caliburn can respond to changes. Collection works but it has limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear from your question how an `Item` relates to a `MoneyControlViewModel`. There are several potential changes to the listed code, though:

1) Change `Collection<Item>` to `ObservableCollection<Item>`

2) Assuming the `Item` class has a `Money` property that returns a `MoneyControlViewModel`... In the XAML, change the DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sell Price">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl x:Name="SellPrice" cal:View.Model="{Binding Money}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This part of your question is not clear:

> How do I implement the Money UserControl for each Item in my list?
>   Wouldn't be a problem if I got the current index of the DataGrid in
>   order to retrieve the Money object from the Item...

It looks like you might want an ItemsControl and use a DataTemplate with a MoneyControl. This question might help: [ItemsControl ItemTemplate Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063031/itemscontrol-itemtemplate-binding)

Comment: Hi, sorry in being so unclear, completely updated my question. I think  that your solution is based on a different problem.

Comment: You are iterating over `Items`. The binding you have specified indicates each `Item` has a `SellPrice` property of type `Money`, e.g. `Item.SellPrice`. For binding issues, you should really look into Snoop WPF: https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: That's correct, each `Item` got this property. I don't see the point why it won't work.

Comment: Well, after I spent some more time on this problem, I found out that the binding was the problem. I did specify the binding of the DataGrid so the binding on the user control was wrong. Anyway, thanks for helping me out and giving some useful tips.

Answer (score 0):

On the class that your `BuyPrice` property it contains, requires you to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and on the `Setter` of the `BuyPrice` you have to raise the implemented method `OnRaisedPropertyChanged("BuyPrice") (.Net 4.0)`.