# XAML equivalent of a foreach

Tags: c#, xaml

Ok so i am trying to pass list of items into a XAML-view in order to "loop" over them. I am used to working with html and have not really understood how to achieve this in XAML.

Here is the class containing Item and also a method that creates a list of Items which I wish to pass to the view:

```
public class Item
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }



        public List<Item> GetList()
        {

            var _test = new List<Item>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var newItem = new Item()
                {
                    ItemId = i++,
                    Name = "Person",
                    Age = 30,
                    Description = "Description",

                };

                _test.Add(newItem);
            }

            return _test;
        } 
    }
```

My view consists of a XAML-template calles GroupDetailPage which consists of a listview to the left and a "detail-view" in the middle which is supposed to switch depending on what item from the list I pick. Here is the XAML for the list-view, untouched:

```
 <ListView
            x:Name="itemListView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="-10,-10,0,0"
            Padding="120,0,0,60"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False"
            SelectionChanged="ItemListView_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="6">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="60" Height="60">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" MaxHeight="40"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Here is the Code-behind for the view. I guess I need to create a method here that gets my list of items and binds it to the view?  I,ve been struggling a lot with this. Im probably to stuck in my MVC-thinking to be able to figure out how to go about this:

```
  public sealed partial class GroupDetailPage1 : Page
    {
        private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
        private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

        /// <summary>
        /// This can be changed to a strongly typed view model.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
        {
            get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// NavigationHelper is used on each page to aid in navigation and 
        /// process lifetime management
        /// </summary>
        public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
        {
            get { return this.navigationHelper; }
        }

        public GroupDetailPage1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // Setup the navigation helper
            this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
            this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;

            // Setup the logical page navigation components that allow
            // the page to only show one pane at a time.
            this.navigationHelper.GoBackCommand = new SimpleMapping.Common.RelayCommand(() => this.GoBack(), () => this.CanGoBack());
            this.itemListView.SelectionChanged += itemListView_SelectionChanged;

            // Start listening for Window size changes 
            // to change from showing two panes to showing a single pane
            Window.Current.SizeChanged += Window_SizeChanged;
            this.InvalidateVisualState();
        }

        void itemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.UsingLogicalPageNavigation())
            {
                this.navigationHelper.GoBackCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }


        private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Assign a bindable group to Me.DefaultViewModel("Group")
            // TODO: Assign a collection of bindable items to Me.DefaultViewModel("Items")

            if (e.PageState == null)
            {
                // When this is a new page, select the first item automatically unless logical page
                // navigation is being used (see the logical page navigation #region below.)
                if (!this.UsingLogicalPageNavigation() && this.itemsViewSource.View != null)
                {
                    this.itemsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Restore the previously saved state associated with this page
                if (e.PageState.ContainsKey("SelectedItem") && this.itemsViewSource.View != null)
                {
                    // TODO: Invoke Me.itemsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo() with the selected
                    //       item as specified by the value of pageState("SelectedItem")

                }
            }
        }
```

Can someone ponit me in the right direction here. Im trying to pass my list of items to the view and hoping that there is an equivalent of the foreach-loop or something similar?
Thank you!

EDIT:
In the constructor for the GroupDetailPage I added this code:

```
 var items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        items = model.GetList();
        DataContext = items;
```

Does this now mean that I can access the in my view?

I added this snippet of code from the link:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"></TextBlock>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Can I somehow bind my properties to the textbloxk in the middle? Does not seem to be any intellisense. Thank you.

Comment: In the textblock you can now use {Binding Age} for example

Answer (score 13):

Foreach is achieved with a list view like `ListBox`, `ListView`, etc. the simplest form is the [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl(v=vs.110).aspx) class (no scrolling, etc.). The list is passed to the view using the `ItemsSource` property. The repeated code block is usually defined in the `ItemTemplate` template.

Have a look at this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063208/876814

Comment: Please se my EDIT if you can

Comment: You need to set the datacontext in typed way or provide the type for the designer

Comment: Read here on how to set the current context type for IntelliSense: https://blog.rsuter.com/recommendations-best-practices-implementing-mvvm-xaml-net-applications/